No rule to make target '/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/third_party/bpftool/include/linux/err.h', needed by 'prog.o'. Stop
I'm building a Docker image.
docker build .
Here's the Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:23.10
WORKDIR /bpftime
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libelf1 libelf-dev zlib1g-dev make cmake git libboost1.74-all-dev \
        binutils-dev libyaml-cpp-dev gcc g++ ca-certificates clang llvm llvm-dev curl
COPY . .
RUN git submodule update --init --recursive
ENV CXX=g++
ENV CC=gcc
RUN make release
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.bpftime/"

Here's the CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL "3.24.0")
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0135 NEW)
endif()

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fno-omit-frame-pointer")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-omit-frame-pointer")
set(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fno-omit-frame-pointer")

#
# Project details
#
project(
  "bpftime"
  VERSION 0.1.0
  LANGUAGES C CXX
)

#
# Set project options
#
include(cmake/CompilerWarnings.cmake)
include(cmake/StandardSettings.cmake)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

find_program(LLVM_CONFIG "llvm-config")
execute_process(COMMAND ${LLVM_CONFIG} --includedir OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR})




if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug")
  message(STATUS "Enabling ubsan for Debug builds; Processor=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")

  if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} MATCHES "arm((32.*)|(v6.*)|(v7.*))")
    message(STATUS "Linking libatomic on arm32 machines..")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -latomic")
  endif()
endif()

message(STATUS "Started CMake for ${PROJECT_NAME} v${PROJECT_VERSION}...\n")

if(UNIX)
  add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-D_DEBUG>") # this will allow to use same _DEBUG macro available in both Linux as well as Windows - MSCV environment. Easy to put Debug specific code.
endif(UNIX)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

#
# Setup alternative names
#
if(${PROJECT_NAME}_USE_ALT_NAMES)
  string(TOLOWER ${PROJECT_NAME} PROJECT_NAME_LOWERCASE)
  string(TOUPPER ${PROJECT_NAME} PROJECT_NAME_UPPERCASE)
else()
  set(PROJECT_NAME_LOWERCASE ${PROJECT_NAME})
  set(PROJECT_NAME_UPPERCASE ${PROJECT_NAME})
endif()

#
# Prevent building in the source directory
#
if(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there.\n")
endif()

include(cmake/libbpf.cmake)

# install frida
include(cmake/frida.cmake)

# Set default value for BPFTIME_LLVM_JIT to ON
option(BPFTIME_LLVM_JIT "Use LLVM as jit backend." ON)

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE YES)

if(${ENABLE_EBPF_VERIFIER})
  add_subdirectory(bpftime-verifier)
else()
  message(STATUS "Skipping ebpf verifier")
  # Catch2
  add_subdirectory(third_party/Catch2)
endif()

# spdlog
add_subdirectory(third_party/spdlog)

set(SPDLOG_INCLUDE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/spdlog/include)

# argparse
add_subdirectory(third_party/argparse)

# main library
add_subdirectory(vm)
add_subdirectory(vm/cli)

add_subdirectory(attach)

add_subdirectory(runtime)
if (${BUILD_BPFTIME_DAEMON})
  add_subdirectory(daemon)
endif()
add_subdirectory(tools)

if(${BUILD_ATTACH_IMPL_EXAMPLE})
  add_subdirectory(example/attach_implementation)
endif()

# benchmark that requires bpftime libraries
add_subdirectory(benchmark)


set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>DLL")

install(TARGETS bpftime-agent bpftime_text_segment_transformer bpftime-syscall-server CONFIGURATIONS Release Debug RelWithDebInfo DESTINATION ~/.bpftime)

Here's Makefile:
.PHONY: install coverage test docs help build clean unit-test-daemon unit-test unit-test-runtime
.DEFAULT_GOAL := help

define BROWSER_PYSCRIPT
import os, webbrowser, sys

try:
    from urllib import pathname2url
except:
    from urllib.request import pathname2url

webbrowser.open("file://" + pathname2url(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])))
endef
export BROWSER_PYSCRIPT

define PRINT_HELP_PYSCRIPT
import re, sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    match = re.match(r'^([a-zA-Z\d_-]+):.*?## (.*)$$', line)
    if match:
        target, help = match.groups()
        print("%-20s %s" % (target, help))
endef
export PRINT_HELP_PYSCRIPT

BROWSER := python3 -c "$$BROWSER_PYSCRIPT"
INSTALL_LOCATION := ~/.local
CXXFLAGS = -I$(shell llvm-config --includedir)



JOBS := 1

help:
     @python3 -c "$$PRINT_HELP_PYSCRIPT" < $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

build-unit-test:
    cmake -Bbuild  -DBPFTIME_ENABLE_UNIT_TESTING=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
    cmake --build build --config Debug --target bpftime_runtime_tests bpftime_daemon_tests  -j$(JOBS)

unit-test-daemon: 
    ./build/daemon/test/bpftime_daemon_tests

unit-test-runtime:
    make -C runtime/test/bpf && cp runtime/test/bpf/*.bpf.o build/runtime/test/
    ./build/runtime/unit-test/bpftime_runtime_tests
    cd build/runtime/test && make && ctest -VV

unit-test: unit-test-daemon unit-test-runtime ## run catch2 unit tests

build: ## build the package with test and all components
    cmake -Bbuild -DBPFTIME_ENABLE_UNIT_TESTING=1 -DBUILD_BPFTIME_DAEMON=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DBPFTIME_LLVM_JIT=1
    cmake --build build --config Debug  -j$(JOBS)

build-iouring: ## build the package with iouring extension
    cmake -Bbuild -DBPFTIME_ENABLE_IOURING_EXT=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo
    cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo  -j$(JOBS)

release: ## build the release version
    cmake -Bbuild  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo \
                   -DSPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL=SPDLOG_LEVEL_INFO -DBPFTIME_LLVM_JIT=1
    cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo --target install  -j$(JOBS)

build-vm: ## build only the core library
    make -C vm build

build-llvm: ## build with llvm as jit backend
    cmake -Bbuild   -DBPFTIME_ENABLE_UNIT_TESTING=1 \
                    -DBPFTIME_LLVM_JIT=1 \
                    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
    cmake --build build --config Debug -j$(JOBS)

clean: ## clean the project
    rm -rf build
    make -C runtime clean
    make -C vm clean

install: release ## Invoke cmake to install..

The error log:
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/bpftime$ docker build .
[+] Building 13.9s (11/11) FINISHED                                docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 431B                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:23.10              2.1s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:23.10@sha256:5cd569b792a8b7b483d909  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                            0.2s
 => => transferring context: 337.13kB                                        0.1s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /bpftime                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-reco  0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] COPY . .                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [5/6] RUN git submodule update --init --recursive                 0.0s
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN make release                                            11.6s
------                                                                            
 > [6/6] RUN make release:
0.320 cmake -Bbuild  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo \
0.320                    -DSPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL=SPDLOG_LEVEL_INFO -DBPFTIME_LLVM_JIT=1
0.460 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
0.541 -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
0.562 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
0.663 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
0.676 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc - skipped
0.676 -- Detecting C compile features
0.677 -- Detecting C compile features - done
0.689 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
0.788 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
0.800 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
0.800 -- Detecting CXX compile features
0.801 -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
0.812 -- Performing Test HAVE_FFI_CALL
0.892 -- Performing Test HAVE_FFI_CALL - Success
0.894 -- Found FFI: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so  
0.899 -- Performing Test Terminfo_LINKABLE
0.981 -- Performing Test Terminfo_LINKABLE - Success
0.983 -- Found Terminfo: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so  
0.991 -- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.13")  
0.993 -- Found zstd: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so  
0.998 -- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.14") 
1.009 -- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
1.031 -- Started CMake for bpftime v0.1.0...
1.031 
1.048 -- copying compiler.h;err.h;filter.h;kernel.h;list.h;overflow.h;ring_buffer.h;types.h from /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux
1.049 -- copying linux/bpf.h;linux/bpf_common.h;linux/btf.h;linux/fcntl.h;linux/if_link.h;linux/if_xdp.h;linux/netdev.h;linux/netlink.h;linux/openat2.h;linux/perf_event.h;linux/pkt_cls.h;linux/pkt_sched.h from /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/ to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi
1.049 -- copying bpf.h;bpf_common.h;btf.h;fcntl.h;if_link.h;if_xdp.h;netdev.h;netlink.h;openat2.h;perf_event.h;pkt_cls.h;pkt_sched.h from /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux
1.050 -- All headers to copy: /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/compiler.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/err.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/filter.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/kernel.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/list.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/overflow.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/ring_buffer.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/types.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/bpf.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/bpf_common.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/btf.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/fcntl.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/if_link.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/if_xdp.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/netdev.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/netlink.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/openat2.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/perf_event.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/pkt_cls.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/pkt_sched.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/bpf.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/bpf_common.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/btf.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/fcntl.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/if_link.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/if_xdp.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/netdev.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/netlink.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/openat2.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/perf_event.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/pkt_cls.h;/bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/pkt_sched.h
1.060 -- System Name: Linux
1.060 -- System Version: 6.4.0-060400-generic
1.060 -- System Processor: x86_64
1.060 -- Using frida: arch=linux-x86_64, version=16.1.2
1.060 -- Frida Core Devkit already downloaded
1.060 -- Frida GUM Devkit already downloaded
1.060 -- Downloading FridaCore from /bpftime/third_party/frida/frida-core-devkit-16.1.2-linux-x86_64.tar.xz
1.073 -- Downloading FridaGum from /bpftime/third_party/frida/frida-gum-devkit-16.1.2-linux-x86_64.tar.xz
1.082 -- Skipping ebpf verifier
1.098 -- Performing Test HAVE_FLAG__ffile_prefix_map__bpftime_third_party_Catch2__
1.189 -- Performing Test HAVE_FLAG__ffile_prefix_map__bpftime_third_party_Catch2__ - Success
1.193 -- Build spdlog: 1.12.0
1.197 -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
1.291 -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
1.292 -- Found Threads: TRUE  
1.292 -- Build type: RelWithDebInfo
1.310 -- Started CMake for vm-bpf v0.1.0...
1.310 
1.310 -- Using llvm-jit
1.332 -- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
1.333 -- LLVM_LIBS=LLVMCore;LLVMOrcJIT;LLVMSupport;LLVMX86CodeGen;LLVMX86Desc;LLVMX86Info
1.340 -- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.74.0")  
1.342 -- Added all header and implementation files.
1.342 
1.342 -- Finished setting up include directories.
1.353 -- Started CMake for runtime v0.1.0...
1.353 
1.357 -- Building for architecture: 
1.357 INFO Headers: include/
1.357 INFO Found the following sources: src/attach/bpf_attach_ctx.cpp;src/handler/handler_manager.cpp;src/handler/map_handler.cpp;src/handler/perf_event_handler.cpp;src/handler/prog_handler.cpp;src/handler/epoll_handler.cpp;src/bpftime_shm.cpp;src/bpftime_shm_internal.cpp;src/bpftime_shm_json.cpp;src/bpftime_prog.cpp;src/ufunc.cpp;src/bpf_helper.cpp;src/bpf_map/userspace/array_map.cpp;src/bpf_map/userspace/hash_map.cpp;src/bpf_map/userspace/ringbuf_map.cpp;src/bpf_map/userspace/perf_event_array_map.cpp;src/bpf_map/userspace/per_cpu_array_map.cpp;src/bpf_map/userspace/per_cpu_hash_map.cpp;src/bpf_map/userspace/prog_array.cpp;extension/extension_helper.cpp;src/bpf_map/shared/array_map_kernel_user.cpp;src/bpf_map/shared/hash_map_kernel_user.cpp;src/bpf_map/shared/percpu_array_map_kernel_user.cpp;src/bpf_map/shared/perf_event_array_kernel_user.cpp
1.357 -- Added all header and implementation files.
1.357 
1.372 -- Using llvm-jit
1.376 -- Configuring done (1.0s)
1.496 -- Generating done (0.1s)
1.503 CMake Warning:
1.503   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
1.503 
1.503     SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL
1.503 
1.503 
1.503 -- Build files have been written to: /bpftime/build
1.515 cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo --target install  -j1
1.524 gmake[1]: Entering directory '/bpftime/build'
1.553 gmake[2]: Entering directory '/bpftime/build'
1.554 gmake[3]: Entering directory '/bpftime/build'
1.562 gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/build'
1.564 gmake[3]: Entering directory '/bpftime/build'
1.570 [  0%] Creating directories for 'libbpf'
1.603 [  0%] No download step for 'libbpf'
1.632 [  1%] No update step for 'libbpf'
1.655 [  1%] No patch step for 'libbpf'
1.676 [  1%] Performing configure step for 'libbpf'
1.706 [  2%] Performing build step for 'libbpf'
1.709 make[4]: Entering directory '/bpftime/third_party/bpftool/libbpf/src'
1.712 make[4]: pkg-config: No such file or directory
1.716   MKDIR    /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs
1.717   MKDIR    /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs
1.718   INSTALL  bpf.h libbpf.h btf.h libbpf_common.h libbpf_legacy.h bpf_helpers.h bpf_helper_defs.h bpf_tracing.h bpf_endian.h bpf_core_read.h skel_internal.h libbpf_version.h usdt.bpf.h
1.719   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/btf.o
1.719   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/bpf.o
1.719   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/libbpf.o
1.720   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/netlink.o
1.720   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/libbpf_errno.o
1.721   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/nlattr.o
1.721   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/str_error.o
1.721   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/libbpf_probes.o
1.722   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/bpf_prog_linfo.o
1.723   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/btf_dump.o
1.724   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/hashmap.o
1.725   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/ringbuf.o
1.726   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/strset.o
1.727   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/gen_loader.o
1.728   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/linker.o
1.739   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/relo_core.o
1.741   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/usdt.o
1.747   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/zip.o
1.752   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/staticobjs/elf.o
1.766   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/bpf.o
1.796   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/btf.o
1.816   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/libbpf.o
1.848   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/libbpf_errno.o
1.860   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/netlink.o
1.870   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/nlattr.o
1.918   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/str_error.o
1.924   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/libbpf_probes.o
1.957   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/bpf_prog_linfo.o
1.970   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/btf_dump.o
2.004   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/hashmap.o
2.024   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/ringbuf.o
2.073   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/strset.o
2.087   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/linker.o
2.161   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/gen_loader.o
2.176   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/relo_core.o
2.232   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/usdt.o
2.246   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/zip.o
2.295   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/sharedobjs/elf.o
2.321   INSTALL  /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/libbpf.pc
8.236   AR       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/libbpf.a
8.267 make[4]: pkg-config: No such file or directory
8.268   CC       /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/libbpf.so.1.3.0
8.341   INSTALL  /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/libbpf.a /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/libbpf.so /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/libbpf.so.1 /bpftime/build/libbpf/libbpf/libbpf.so.1.3.0
8.351 make[4]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/third_party/bpftool/libbpf/src'
8.377 [  3%] No install step for 'libbpf'
8.412 [  3%] Completed 'libbpf'
8.446 gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/build'
8.460 [  3%] Built target libbpf
8.464 gmake[3]: Entering directory '/bpftime/build'
8.478 gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/build'
8.480 gmake[3]: Entering directory '/bpftime/build'
8.487 [  3%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/pkt_sched.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/pkt_sched.h
8.516 [  3%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux/compiler.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/compiler.h
8.544 [  3%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux/err.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/err.h
8.572 [  3%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux/filter.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/filter.h
8.597 [  3%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux/kernel.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/kernel.h
8.637 [  4%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux/list.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/list.h
8.673 [  4%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux/overflow.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/overflow.h
8.698 [  5%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux/ring_buffer.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/ring_buffer.h
8.728 [  5%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/linux/types.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/types.h
8.761 [  5%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/bpf.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/bpf.h
8.798 [  6%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/bpf_common.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/bpf_common.h
8.828 [  6%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/btf.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/btf.h
8.856 [  6%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/fcntl.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/fcntl.h
8.882 [  7%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/if_link.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/if_link.h
8.912 [  7%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/if_xdp.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/if_xdp.h
8.946 [  7%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/netdev.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/netdev.h
8.968 [  8%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/netlink.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/netlink.h
9.001 [  8%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/openat2.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/openat2.h
9.030 [  9%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/perf_event.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/perf_event.h
9.059 [  9%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/pkt_cls.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/pkt_cls.h
9.088 [  9%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi//linux/pkt_sched.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//uapi/linux/pkt_sched.h
9.115 [  9%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/bpf.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/bpf.h
9.143 [  9%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/bpf_common.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/bpf_common.h
9.180 [ 10%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/btf.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/btf.h
9.209 [ 11%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/fcntl.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/fcntl.h
9.245 [ 12%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/if_link.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/if_link.h
9.278 [ 12%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/if_xdp.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/if_xdp.h
9.322 [ 12%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/netdev.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/netdev.h
9.360 [ 12%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/netlink.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/netlink.h
9.394 [ 13%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/openat2.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/openat2.h
9.431 [ 13%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/perf_event.h
9.460 [ 14%] Copying file /bpftime/third_party/libbpf//include/uapi/linux/pkt_cls.h to /bpftime/build/libbpf//linux/pkt_cls.h
9.488 [ 15%] Copying headers
9.501 Copying relo_core.h
9.531 Copying hashmap.h
9.558 Copying nlattr.h
9.588 Copying libbpf_internal.h
9.596 gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/build'
9.611 [ 15%] Built target copy_headers
9.614 gmake[3]: Entering directory '/bpftime/build'
9.622 gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/build'
9.624 gmake[3]: Entering directory '/bpftime/build'
9.632 [ 16%] Creating directories for 'bpftool'
9.656 [ 17%] No download step for 'bpftool'
9.680 [ 17%] No update step for 'bpftool'
9.716 [ 17%] No patch step for 'bpftool'
9.750 [ 17%] Performing configure step for 'bpftool'
9.780 [ 17%] Performing build step for 'bpftool'
9.784 make[4]: Entering directory '/bpftime/third_party/bpftool/src'
10.55 ...                        libbfd: [ on  ]
10.55 ...               clang-bpf-co-re: [ on  ]
10.55 ...                          llvm: [ on  ]
10.55 ...                        libcap: [ OFF ]
11.46 make[4]: *** No rule to make target '/home/pegasus/Documents/bpftime/third_party/bpftool/include/linux/err.h', needed by 'prog.o'.  Stop.
11.46 make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
11.53 make[4]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/third_party/bpftool/src'
11.53 gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/bpftool.dir/build.make:86: bpftool/src/bpftool-stamp/bpftool-build] Error 2
11.53 gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/build'
11.53 gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:696: CMakeFiles/bpftool.dir/all] Error 2
11.53 gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/build'
11.53 gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
11.53 gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/bpftime/build'
11.53 make: *** [Makefile:62: release] Error 2
------
Dockerfile:10
--------------------
   8 |     ENV CXX=g++
   9 |     ENV CC=gcc
  10 | >>> RUN make release
  11 |     ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.bpftime/"
  12 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c make release" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

How to fix this error? Previously the codebase had FROM ubuntu:23.04.It showed version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /bpftime/third_party/bpftool/src/bootstrap/bpftool)
. So I updated the ubuntu version to 23.10 now I'm seeing this error how can I fix it?
